# Excluding/Including tables in mysqldump AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out how to exclude or include specific tables when doing mysqldump command on AWS via terminal.

Background: I have a WordPress multisite but only need the tables with the first 3 characters "wp_" all of the other tables with prefixes like "wp_1", "wp_2", etc. I don't need in the dump file.

Here is the code I am using to generate the dump file which works but grabs all the tables in the database:

```
mysqldump -h RDS instance endpoint \ 
-u user \ 
-p databasename \ 
--port=3306 \ 
--single-transaction \ 
--routines \ 
--triggers \ 
--databases databasename > path/rds-dump.sql
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what is difference between - 'tables with the first 3 characters "wp_"' and "wp_1", "wp_2". Could you clarify more detailed. It would be better with some real examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqldump ignore table with wildcard](http://serverfault.com/questions/511333/mysqldump-ignore-table-with-wildcard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that I have implemented when I faced same issue is that I created a file with all the required table names. Now I just have to Iterate through the file and take the dump of each table and append it in the same dump file. 
For example:

```
for i in $(cat requiredtables.txt);do mysqldump -h RDS_instance -u user -p'password' db_name $i >> db_dump.sql;done
```

Comment: That appears to work, but the problem is that you don't necessarily get a backup where all the tables are consistent with each other.  If you catch a parent table too early and a child table too late, you could have a stranded foreign key issue, for example.  Dumping all the desired tables in a single execution of mysqldump is a better/safer approach, particularly when you use `--single-transaction` (as you always should) so that all the tables are consistent with the snapshot of the database as it appeared when the backup first started.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at this a while ago, when moving my own websites, and my conclusion is it's not possible. There's probably a way to process the dump file after export, but I probably wouldn't bother without a really good reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, but you can always dump the entire db and create an SQL query that drops the unwanted tables. This however will not shorten mysqldump time.